# Node using CPU 100% with GULP

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I do not know what could be wrong. When I'm developing most of the time my CPU is using 100%. I have already tried to do this gulpfile.js in several ways and continue with the same error. I read in other posts that there may be some looping I'm doing with no feedback, but I do not know where that error is. Can anyone with more experience help me?

My GULP file is:

```
'use strict';

var gulp         = require('gulp');
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();
var util         = require('gulp-util');
var compass      = require('gulp-compass');

var error        = util.colors.bold.red;

function errorHandler(err) {
    console.log(error(err.toString()));
    this.emit('end');
}

var optionsCompass = {
    config_file : 'config.rb',
    css         : './css',
    sass        : './scss',
    image       : './img'
};

gulp.task('scss', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(compass(optionsCompass).on('error', errorHandler))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('server', function() {
    gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(compass(optionsCompass).on('error', errorHandler))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'todentro.localhost/'
    });

    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', ['scss']);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['server']);
```

Comment: Do you have a lot of files in the folders being watched ? If the `gulp.watch` functions have too much stuff to watch, that can cause a lot of load. Try narrowing down the `watch` functions, for instance concentrate all `.js `files to one folder and watch only that `gulp.watch('./js/*.js', browserSync.reload);`

Comment: Hmm, i will try.

Comment: I'm monitoring and it seems to be stable. I do not believe it was that simple to solve. Thank you for your help.